# Machine name in Internet Information Services (IIS)

Tags: iis

when I open IIS manager, I see under 'Start Page', my 'machine name' I need to know from where does the Internet Information Services (IIS) fetches the machine name? Is machine name stored in any XML file or does IIS fetches it from any other file? It will be helpful if anyone provides the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It fetches the machine name from Windows API because there is only one machine name in Windows.

To see that machine name:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Open System (under System and Security category)
3. Read the name under the third section titled "Computer name, domain name, and workgroup settings"

You can even change it by clicking on the Change Settings link to the right, under the same section.

To get the machine name in Command Prompt, type:

```
echo %computername%
```

To get the machine name in Windows PowerShell, type:

```
$env:computername
```

...Or:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
```